# Call fragment method from own class

Tags: android-fragments

*What is the correct way of calling a fragment method from another class?*

I have a class ‘ParseCommands.java’ as such:

```
public class ParseCommands {

   public static Context context;

   < call to FragmentSettings.doStuff() >

}
```

I would like to call the method doStuff() in my Fragment:

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

private static Activity a;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
}

public void doStuff(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(a, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

I apply my fragments via tabs so I don’t use the fragment manager to set them up, however I’ve tried the following to try to call the method but it doesn’t seem to work:

```
Activity act = (Activity) context;
FragmentManager fm = act.getFragmentManager();
FragmentSettings fs = (FragmentSettings) m.findFragmentById(R.xml.fragment_settings);
fs.doStuff("it actually worked!");
```

and I’ve tried declaring doStuff as static and calling it like:

```
FragmentSettings.doStuff
```

Both methods don’t seem to work...

**What is the correct way of doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a context object in the ParseCommands class you can use the LocalBroadCastManager to send a message to your Fragment. Your fragment will have to have a BroadcastReceiver implementation and from the onReceive method you can call the doStuff method.

For an implementation check out: [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)